# Cannot find source links in source file but still shows in apt update

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, gnupg, mssql

I'm new to this, and I was trying to install MS SQL in 18.04. But I faced some issue and wanted to remove everything regarding MS SQL for new.

So I `purge` everything and removed all GPG from `/etc/apt/sources.list` related to Microsoft.

Also I removed the GPG added from

`curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -` 
using command

`sudo apt-key list` and `sudo apt-key del xxxxxx`

Now when I do `apt update` I see below logs:

```
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease        
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Err:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Fetched 88.7 kB in 1s (90.6 kB/s)                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/prod/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have not much of an idea what I was doing :). But all I want to understand what happening here and what I should do to remove it now.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory, should some of your Microsoft source located there. Also this `find` query might be helpful to you.

```
sudo find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec grep -i 'https://packages.microsoft.com' {} \; -print
```

This will return the file which contain `https://packages.microsoft.com` string.